# Is it possible to backup and restore Databricks database from one environment to another, like PROD to Dev?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

we need to backup restore the databricks database from one environment to another like PROD to Dev, is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean under the database?

Comment: entire metastore we need to move from environment to another

Answer (score 0):

1. backup the metastore for the database
2. copy the storage to the new storage spot.  S3 copy if in AWS
3. restore metadata replacing the location of the schema to the new storage